# Why whenever I login with different users, I see the same cart information. Should be different for every user

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

This is the controller, whenever I add a new item to the cart, and logout and again login with different user, I see the same cart. Please help how can I add a session for cart. How do I show different cart for each user, as whatever they add should be shown on the cart page. And when I login from another browser, everything gets deleted and doesn't get stored.

```
// Add the cart
function add_to_cart(){ 
    $this->addToCart($this->input->post('id'), 
                    $this->input->post('name'), 
                    $this->input->post('price'), 
                    $this->input->post('qty'),
                    "product");
}

function remove_from_cart(){
  $row_id = $this->input->get("row_id");
  $this->removeFromCart($row_id);      

  redirect('product/cart');
}

function update_from_cart(){
  $row_id = $this->input->post("row_id");
  $qty    = $this->input->post("qty");
```

Comment: cart is different for each and every user. Seems your doing something wrong

Comment: PHP sessions are temporarily stored on your server, the persons browsers keeps a key for this temp storage and uses that data. Logging in and out of different accounts will not change where the users PHP session data points to. To store a users cart unique to them, you need to store it in a database (mySQL recommended).